# How to use single recyclerview to display following data?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to use single recyclerview to display title n data as following
Eg.
Education
*10th 
*12th science
*Be comp

Work experience

> Comp 2
>   Comp 3

Reference

> mr x
>   mr y
>   mr z

Attachment

> Doc 1
>   Doc 2
>   Doc 3

Response contains different arraylist of different model classes

Answer (score 0):

First set layout manager like this:

```
 RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),3));
```

Then use try this in your Adapter:

```
public class adapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.sampleViewHolder> {

public adapter(ArrayList<Comp> compArrayList, ArrayList<Mr> mrArrayList, ArrayList<Doc> docArrayList) {
    // ....
}


@NonNull
@Override
public sampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull sampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int numberOfYourArrayList = 2;

    switch (position % numberOfYourArrayList) {
        case 0:
            // use for array list 1 ( Comp )
            break;
        case 1:
            // use for array list 2 ( Mr )
            break;
        case 2:
            // use for array list 3 ( Doc  )
            break;
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class sampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public sampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

}